# Embedding a file into JAR using Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, file-io, jar

My project directory has two packages

1. src (contains source files)
2. scripts (contains sql scripts)

The problem is when I try to run the executable jar file from a command line. I get an error `...../schemaDB.sql (the filename, directory name, volume name etc)`. I assumed it was having problems finding my scripts. When I run it in netbeans I don't get such errors, why is that ?

the way I currently am loading the file is like so,

```
  public void loadScr (String name) {
     URL f = Init.class.getClassLoader().getResource("scripts/"+ name);
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f.getPath()));
     ...process script
```

Comment: Netbeans is probably adding your scripts folder to its classpath, but not adding it to the jar file.  Verify that your jar file contains the scripts folder...

Comment: Google around about adding a file to a jar with NetBeans.  You'll surely find dozens of links to similar questions on this site.